# SharePoint2010 is using older version of Workflow instead of new one

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a Workflow in created in SharePoint designer 2010 that starts when an item in the list is changed. The problem is that SharePoint keeps using the older version of the Workflow after I save and publish my new workflow.

The reason I know is the old version is because the first action in the workflow is to log to history the version date (a date I change every time I change the workflow) of the Workflow; the action looks like: *Log "2015-04-10" to the Workflow History*). When I go to the history of the workflow for items changed yesterday or today, I still see "2015-03-09" (an old version of the workflow) in the history (with an history entry date of today in the **Date Occurred Column** of the history).

What I have tried: I tried removing every workflow from "Library/List tab", "Workflow Setting" and then publishing my new workflow from the Designer. but it is still somehow picking up the old version.

I am using SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue in the past. You need to clear SharePoint Designer's cache:

1. Close SharePoint Designer
2. Go to
   %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WebsiteCache, Or, on older versions of windows: C:\Documents and Settings\%USER%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebSiteCache
3. Delete either (choose one, based on how annoyed you are by now):
   a) All folders. 
   b) The folder that "looks most like your site" (can be more than one: site, site(1), etc, and should be the bottom level site, not the root site)
   c) The relevant DLL in that folder.
4. Start SharePoint Designer, save the workflow again, it should be ok.

It would be safe to delete all folders in that directory.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098563/why-do-sharepoint-designer-workflows-when-edited-seem-not-to-update-on-the-sha)

Answer (score 0):

Check the **check box** to start workflow also on item create. 
This can trigger the update to new version.

Then you can revert your changes.